# Copy video to phone from PC without Windows harping about converting to WMV

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, video-conversion, wmv

I don't do buffering so when I want to show someone a video I download the source file and copy it from my PC/Windows 7 to my phone via a USB cable.

Every time I copy a video file Windows harasses me to convert it to WMV format.

How do I permanently disable Windows 7 from asking me to convert media files before they begin to copy to a mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are copying from a source drive that stores your media. The simplest answer is to disable autoplay, or adjust your autoplay settings.

Check out [this help site (Microsoft)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-autoplay-settings#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: You could also remove Windows Media Player/Windows Movie Maker if you don't use these tools. You would need to install a 3rd party media player (such as VLC) to regain playback functionality.
[Here is a how-to](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/uninstall-windows-media-player-from-windows-7/) on how to uninstall WMP.

Comment: I'll uninstall WMP when I get back to that computer. I use VLC. :-)